# How do I Integrate OpenID into MVC4 Web API

Tags: openid, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dotnetopenauth

I am writing a Web API using MVC4 that should be consumed by multiple client types. I want to use the OpenID to authenticate.

I already have downloaded the DotNetOpenAuth NuGet package, but so far all of the examples are for a client app, rather than an API.

My problem is simple. I want to have clients send an authentication request to my API. The API authenticates with an OpenID provider. The API then sets whatever it needs to in order to use the [Authorize] tags throughout the web api calls.

I understand that in .NET applications, that the FormsAuthentication.SetCookie could be called, but is this also an easy-to-implement solution for other languages?

The question in a nutshell. How do I integrate OpenID into an MVC4 web api that allows for the use of the Authorize tag that can be called and consumed by multiple languages?

Comment: For people coming back to this, the NuGet package for DotNetOpenAuth doesn't seem to be completely up to date (as of today). It does not have the OAUTH2 namespace included. Instead use this [sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/).

Comment: Take a look at this project http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may be confusing the roles of authentication and authorization.  It sounds like your Web API needs *both*.

Let's start with authorization.  Every API (that is, a web URL that is accessed by a client app other than a browser) either permits anonymous access or must be authorized (i.e. authorization).  Authorization is *OAuth*'s domain.  OAuth (v2, presumably) describes how a client authorizes a call to your WebAPI.

Presumably as part of the authorization process, a user logs into your service.  This step of logging in the user is *authentication*.  And it is orthogonal to authorization.  Whether you authenticate the user via OpenID, username/password, X.509 cert, etc., should be irrelevant to how your WebAPI calls are authorized.  In other words, your WebAPI methods shouldn't care how the user authenticated (read: no OpenID ties whatever).  What they'll have is an authorization filter applied to them that verifies the authorization on an incoming request and translates it to a few pieces of information including the username of the account that authorized the access, the level of access, the id of the authorized client, etc.

So a step at a time, the whole scenario might go something like this:

1. A user operating a 3rd party client app (let's assume for simplicity that this client app is a 3rd party web application) wants to use functionality that requires the client access your WebAPI in the user's name.
2. The client needs to obtain authorization for limited impersonation of the user as the client makes calls to your WebAPI.  They start with an OAuth 2 redirect to the authorization endpoint at your service.  If this is implemented using DotNetOpenAuth this could use the [WebServerClient](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v4.1/html/T_DotNetOpenAuth_OAuth2_WebServerClient.htm) class.
3. Your authorization endpoint fills the role of an OAuth 2 Authorization Server, and as such, uses DotNetOpenAuth's [AuthorizationServer](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v4.1/html/T_DotNetOpenAuth_OAuth2_AuthorizationServer.htm) class.  The first thing it does is check to see if there is an ASP.NET forms authentication cookie included in the request.  This cookie is a natural indication as to whether the user has logged into your service on their browser already, and if so, who that user is.  Checking for this cookie is a simple call to [Controller.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx).  Note that your authorization endpoint is MVC rather than  WebAPI because its response is to the browser/user, not the client app.  Let's assume there is no such cookie and `Controller.User` is null (or `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false`).  Refer to the OAuthAuthorizationServer sample for how to implement this endpoint.
4. Your authorization endpoint responds with a redirect to the user login page, including a `redirectUrl` parameter in the query string that retains the full incoming OAuth 2 authorization request URL.
5. Your user login page is an MVC endpoint that acts as an OpenID Relying Party.  This endpoint uses DotNetOpenAuth's [OpenIdRelyingParty](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v4.1/html/T_DotNetOpenAuth_OpenId_RelyingParty_OpenIdRelyingParty.htm) class.  Note that this endpoint knows nothing of OAuth 2 or authorization stuff.  It merely authenticates the user.  After authenticating the user, it redirects back to the URL in the `redirectUrl` argument.  Refer to the OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc sample for how to do this.
6. The authorization endpoint repeats its prior step, except this time there is a FormsAuthentication cookie so it proceeds to display a page to the user asking if they want to authorize the client to access the user's data.  The user clicks yes. (beware: implement XSRF and clickjacking mitigations on this user authorization page).
7. The authorization endpoint processes the user's affirmative response and calls `AuthorizationServer` to create the authorization record and return the response to the client.  One of the results of this call is the formulation of a redirect response to the client that gives it an authorization code.
8. The browser is now pulling at a URL of the client app that passes it the authorization code.  The client then uses the `WebServerClient` class to exchange the authorization code for an access token (and usually a refresh token as well).
9. The client app now makes calls to your WebAPI URLs directly, including the access token it obtained via OAuth 2 in the HTTP Authorization header.
10. Your WebAPI fills the role of the OAuth2 Resource Server, and the authorize filter attribute you apply to your WebAPI methods to validate the incoming OAuth 2 access token uses the DotNetOpenAuth [ResourceServer](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v4.1/html/T_DotNetOpenAuth_OAuth2_ResourceServer.htm) class to do its work.  You can refer to the OAuthResourceServer sample, or even better, [David Christiansen's WebAPI sample](https://github.com/DavidChristiansen/DotNetOpenAuth.WebAPI.40) for how to do this.

That's the whole story.  And yes, the client role is easy to write regardless of language or library that they happen to be using.

BTW, the DotNetOpenAuth samples I refer to are not distributed via NuGet.  You [get the samples from SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/latest/).